# Enable ivy fuzzy matching everywhere, except in swiper

Tags: ivy

I have been using `flx-ido-mode` for a while and I like it. Ivy can behave the same way by using `ivy--regex-fuzzy`.

The problem is that `swiper` will also use fuzzy matching now and in this case I don't really like it (at least not as a default, all the time).

So I'd like to continue using fuzzy matching with Ivy except in `swiper`. Is there a way to configure this? Or can I somehow tell `swiper` that I'm really looking for "this" substring right now by prefixing something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I'd like to continue using fuzzy matching with Ivy except in `swiper`.

The variable that determines which "regexp builder", as Ivy refers to these functions, is used for which collection function is `ivy-re-builders-alist`:

```
ivy-re-builders-alist is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is ((t . ivy--regex-plus))

Documentation:
An alist of regex building functions for each collection function.

Each key is (in order of priority):
1. The actual collection function, e.g. ‘read-file-name-internal’.
2. The symbol passed by :caller into ‘ivy-read’.
3. ‘this-command’.
4. t.

Each value is a function that should take a string and return a
valid regex or a regex sequence (see below).

Possible choices: ‘ivy--regex’, ‘regexp-quote’,
‘ivy--regex-plus’, ‘ivy--regex-fuzzy’.

If a function returns a list, it should format like this:
’(("matching-regexp" . t) ("non-matching-regexp") ...).

The matches will be filtered in a sequence, you can mix the
regexps that should match and that should not match as you
like.
```

So, in order to change the default regexp builder from `ivy--regex-plus` to `ivy--regex-fuzzy`, but keep the former for `swiper`, you could

```el
(setq ivy-re-builders-alist
      '((swiper . ivy--regex-plus)
        (t      . ivy--regex-fuzzy)))
```

or, more programmatically,

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ivy
  (push (cons #'swiper (cdr (assq t ivy-re-builders-alist)))
        ivy-re-builders-alist)
  (push (cons t #'ivy--regex-fuzzy) ivy-re-builders-alist))
```

This is described in more detail in [`(ivy) Completion Styles`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#completion-styles).

> I don't really like [fuzzy matching] (at least not as a default, all the time)

Ivy allows you to rotate the regexp builder on the fly via its hydra interface. The fairly hidden last sentence of [`(ivy) ivy--regex-fuzzy`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#ivy--regex-fuzzy) alludes to this, and a more complete description can be found under [`(ivy) Hydra in the minibuffer`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#hydra-in-the-minibuffer), but it looks like the manual is a bit outdated given [it's been a little while](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/855) since the last release.

The upshot is that, since [2017-07-04](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/ae438ff62fa3d9b98d899afc0e97c13be2148725), Ivy allows you to cycle through regexp builders during completion via <kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> (`ivy-rotate-preferred-builders`). **Edit**: as pointed out by `Asme Just` in [a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36745/enable-ivy-fuzzy-matching-everywhere-except-in-swiper/36748?noredirect=1#comment73928_36748), the default key binding was changed to <kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> on [2019-02-06](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/28e88ab23a191420a93a4f920ca076674ee53f94).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the completion cycling a bit? For example if I have started a swiper search, C-o will immediately give me a "command-execute: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ivy-hydra" message.

Comment: @B_old Try installing the optional `ivy-hydra` package first. The moral question of whether a default keybinding should exist for an optional (i.e. not always installed) feature [has already been raised](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1127) and the status quo seems unlikely to change soon. If you have other questions about `ivy-hydra` which the manual does not address, please consider creating new Emacs SE questions for them.

Comment: (`ivy-rotate-preferred-builders`) is `C-o M`  for me currently by default.

Comment: @AsmeJust Thanks, that was a backward-incompatible change made just over 2 weeks ago: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/28e88ab23a191420a93a4f920ca076674ee53f94

Comment: For those stumbling on this page and blindly copy/pasting the top response, only to find out that it doesn't work, make sure you haven't rebound `C-s` to something else in swiper. In my case, I'd rebound it to `swiper-isearch`, so replacing `(swiper . ivy--regex-plus)` with `(swiper-isearch . ivy--regex-plus)` in the accepted answer fixed it.

Comment: @user4601931 Indeed, this Q&A was about `swiper` the command, not `swiper` the package as a whole. `ivy-re-builders-alist` works per-command, so if you're using the `swiper-isearch` command, you should indeed enter that in place of `swiper`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to turn off regex matching in swiper, but keep it active elsewhere, add this to your `user-init-file`:

```el
(setq ivy-re-builders-alist
      '((swiper . regexp-quote)
        (t      . ivy--regex-fuzzy)))
```

If you want to deactivate it just once, hit `M-r` in swiper.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the handy `M-r` binding. Note, however, that OP only specified they want fuzzy matching disabled; which regexp builder should replace it was left unclear.