# How to toggle regex for helm/ivy user input?

Tags: helm, regular-expressions, ivy

IIUC, all `helm` commands (including `helm-swoop`, `swiper-helm`) have regex enabled by default for user input.  Can we toggle/disable it by some command/shortcut?  Let me know if I missed something.

Using `isearch` as an analogy: default `helm` is similar to `isearch-forward-regexp` that always uses regex engine. Do we have `helm-no-regex` that is similar to `isearch-forward` which doesn't use regex?

For example, in `helm-mini`, when I search for "xy .c", I would like to match files like "xy_test.c", but not "xyzc.h".  I know that we can escape the '.' (i.e., search for "xy \.c"), but I would like to escape all regex symbols by default.  Is it possible?

I guess a possible solution is to pre-process input string by escaping all special characters?

(If it's not possible for helm, how about ivy/counsel/swiper?)

Answer (score 6):

> If it's not possible for helm, how about ivy/counsel/swiper?

Ivy is the library which Swiper search and Counsel convenience functions are backed by, so changing the way Ivy interprets its input affects the other two packages by extension.

> IIUC, all `helm` commands (including `helm-swoop`, `swiper-helm`) have regex enabled by default for user input.

This is also true of Ivy; see below.

> How to toggle regex for helm/ivy user input?

If you know ahead of time how you want Ivy to interpret input by default, or for any command in particular, you can customise `ivy-re-builders-alist`:

```
ivy-re-builders-alist is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is ((t . ivy--regex-plus))

Documentation:
An alist of regex building functions for each collection function.

Each key is (in order of priority):
1. The actual collection function, e.g. ‘read-file-name-internal’.
2. The symbol passed by :caller into ‘ivy-read’.
3. ‘this-command’.
4. t.

Each value is a function that should take a string and return a
valid regex or a regex sequence (see below).

Possible choices: ‘ivy--regex’, ‘regexp-quote’,
‘ivy--regex-plus’, ‘ivy--regex-fuzzy’, ‘ivy--regex-ignore-order’.

If a function returns a list, it should format like this:
’(("matching-regexp" . t) ("non-matching-regexp") ...).

The matches will be filtered in a sequence, you can mix the
regexps that should match and that should not match as you
like.
```

See [`(ivy) Completion Styles`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#completion-styles) and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36748/15748 for further pointers.

> Can we toggle/disable [regex matching] by some command/shortcut?

You can hot-swap completion styles during completion via <kbd>C-o</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>(`hydra-ivy/ivy-rotate-preferred-builders`), but for this you need to install the optional `ivy-hydra` package; see [`(ivy) Hydra in the minibuffer`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#hydra-in-the-minibuffer).

Alternatively, you can bind the command `ivy-rotate-preferred-builders` to a key of your choosing in `ivy-minibuffer-map`.

You can customise which regexp builders either of these commands rotate via `ivy-preferred-re-builders`:

```
ivy-preferred-re-builders is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is
((ivy--regex-plus . "ivy")
 (ivy--regex-ignore-order . "order")
 (ivy--regex-fuzzy . "fuzzy"))

Documentation:
Alist of preferred re-builders with display names.
This list can be rotated with ‘ivy-rotate-preferred-builders’.
```

> Do we have `helm-no-regex` that is similar to `isearch-forward` which doesn't use regex?

The closest thing that Ivy provides for this by default is the `regexp-quote` regexp builder:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ivy
  ;; All searches are literal by default
  (add-to-list 'ivy-re-builders-alist (cons t #'regexp-quote))
  (add-to-list 'ivy-preferred-re-builders (cons #'regexp-quote "quote")))
```

> For example, in `helm-mini`, when I search for "xy .c", I would like to match files like "xy_test.c", but not "xyzc.h".  I know that we can escape the '.' (i.e., search for "xy \.c"), but I would like to escape all regex symbols by default.  Is it possible?

Ivy does not, OOTB, provide a function which interprets everything except spaces literally, but you can write one yourself, or suggest such a function on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues).

Here are two such sample regexp builders. They result in identical matching behaviour, except the former is sensitive to the ordering of the whitespace-separated substrings, whereas the latter is not. You can add them to `ivy-re-builders-alist` and `ivy-preferred-re-builders` as previously shown.

```el
(defun my-regexp-quote (string)
  "Build a regexp suitable for Ivy from STRING.
Convert whitespace to \".*\" and `regexp-quote' everything else."
  (mapconcat #'regexp-quote (split-string string) ".*"))

(defun my-regexp-quote-dynamic (string)
  "Build a regexp alist suitable for Ivy from STRING.
Has a similar effect to `my-regexp-quote', except the order of
whitespace-separated substrings is ignored."
  (mapcar (lambda (substring)
            (cons (regexp-quote substring) t))
          (split-string string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `helm-ff-fuzzy-matching` variable.

As the docs say:

> Enable fuzzy matching for ‘helm-find-files’ when non--nil.
>
> See ‘helm-ff--transform-pattern-for-completion’ for more info.

It’s default value is `t`, you may want to set it to `nil` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Tried `(setq helm-ff-fuzzy-matching nil)`, but it still interprets the dot char as any char (i.e., still using regex).  Thanks anyway.

Comment: fuzzy is unlinked to regular expressions.