# How to enable fuzzy matching in Ivy's prompt-buffer via use-package?

Tags: use-package, ivy, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-matching

I used to use Helm and I really liked it. After watching System Crafter's YouTube series called ["Emacs from Scratch"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74zOY-vgkyw&list=PLEoMzSkcN8oPH1au7H6B7bBJ4ZO7BXjSZ), I decided to use the configuration showcased. The YouTuber prefers Ivy instead of Helm. This is the configuration for the first episode [when Ivy is shown for the first time](https://github.com/daviwil/emacs-from-scratch/blob/3075158cae210060888001c0d76a58a4178f6a00/init.el).

He does the installation and configuration via `use-package`. This is my almost identical use of the same approach:

```lisp
;; Using Ivy from System Crafters
(use-package ivy
  :diminish ;keeps ivy out of the mode line
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
         :map ivy-minibuffer-map
         ;("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)    
         ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-l" . ivy-done)
         ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
         :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1))
```

I miss two things from Helm: (1) Helm fuzzy matching, and (2) Helm's prompt-buffer listing the last used command at the top of the prompt-buffer.

Since Ivy is configurable, I have been trying to fulfill my desires. Some answers in [Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36745/enable-ivy-fuzzy-matching-everywhere-except-in-swiper) pointed to using:

```lisp
(setq ivy-re-builders-alist
      '((swiper . ivy--regex-plus)
        (t      . ivy--regex-fuzzy)))
```

Thus, I tried tweaking the ivy configuration to be:

```lisp
;; Using Ivy from System Crafters
(use-package ivy
  :diminish ;keeps ivy out of the mode line
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
         :map ivy-minibuffer-map
         ;("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)    
         ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-l" . ivy-done)
         ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
         :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  '((ivy-mode 1)
    (t      . ivy--regex-fuzzy)))
```

But, it did not work out to solve problem (1). At the same time, I tried installing `ivy-prescient` to have the last used command listed first and solve problem (2). It seems to work, not sure if this is the best approach, though:

```lisp
;; Make the last used command be the first-one
(use-package ivy-prescient
  :init
  (ivy-prescient-mode 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the fuzzy match problem (not sure if this is the best way):

```lisp
(use-package ivy
  :diminish ;keeps ivy out of the mode line
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
         :map ivy-minibuffer-map
         ;("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)    
         ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-l" . ivy-done)
         ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
         :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  '((ivy-mode 1)
    (ivy--regex-fuzzy 1)))
```

I am still not sure if this is the best approach for `ivy-prescient`. But it seems to do the trick:

```lisp
;; Make the last used command be the first-one
(use-package ivy-prescient
  :init
  (ivy-prescient-mode 1))
```